# Animating non-animatable properties with CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

In my app I'm animating the opacity of elements on the page with something like:

```
.s {
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 250ms;
}
```

(with vendor-specific versions, of course). And then

```
.s.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

So the animation starts when the `hidden` class is assigned. Problem is, mouse events are still detected on elements with opacity zero, which I don't want, so I need to either set `visibility` to `hidden` or `display` to `none` *after* the transition is finished. I would hope to be able to do something like:

```
.s {
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: 250ms;
    transition-delay:    0, 250ms;
}
```

and then

```
.s.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

to use the CSS transition machinery to do this painlessly. As far as I can tell, that doesn't work because `visibility` is a non-animatable property. But other transition frameworks such as d3 *do* handle non-animatable properties, in the obvious way by simply setting the value when the transition starts, or when it ends.

The best I've been able to come up with is to use the `transitionend` event (and its browser-specific variants such as `oTransitionEnd`) to catch the end of the transition and set `visibility` at that point, but I'm wondering if there's any easier way, preferably sticking purely to CSS. Or, as the title of my question implies, are non-animatable properties just that?

Comment: Found a useful write-up on this topic at http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`visibility` *is* an animatable property, [see the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-).

Which means your `.hidden` class will work as you have described. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ianlunn/xef3s/

Edit: the spec isn't perfectly clear:

> visibility: if one of the values is ‘visible’, interpolated as a
>   discrete step where values of the timing function between 0 and 1 map
>   to ‘visible’ and other values of the timing function (which occur only
>   at the start/end of the transition or as a result of ‘cubic-bezier()’
>   functions with Y values outside of [0, 1]) map to the closer endpoint;
>   if neither value is ‘visible’ then not interpolable.

But this is what I believe it means:

`visibility` doesn't smoothly animate between a range of `visible` and `hidden` in the way that opacity animates between 1 - 0. It simply switches between `visible` and `hidden` at the start and end states of the transition.

Providing the transition is either going to or from `visibility`, then a transition will occur. If trying to transition between `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: collapse` for example, those values are "not interpolable" and the transition would not occur.

So in my example, `opacity` causes the element to fade out and then at the end of the transition, `visibility` snaps to `hidden`.

Comment: Firefox does not support transitioning `visibility` yet - http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xef3s/2

Comment: You're missing the `opacity` declaration. This works in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/ianlunn/B8dwR/

Comment: That's because Firefox is animating the `opacity` property, isn't it?

Comment: Scratch that - I probably don't know how exactly animating `visibility` is supposed to work. I see this in the spec but don't really understand it: "**visibility**: if one of the values is ‘visible’, interpolated as a discrete step where values of the timing function between 0 and 1 map to ‘visible’ and other values of the timing function (which occur only at the start/end of the transition or as a result of ‘cubic-bezier()’ functions with Y values outside of [0, 1]) map to the closer endpoint; if neither value is ‘visible’ then not interpolable."

Comment: Correct. The OP doesn't want to *just* hide the element via `visibility: hidden`, they want the element to fade and then have `visibility: hidden` to apply at the end so the element is no longer drawn (and the `cursor` declaration in my example no longer affects the area where the element was).

I will update my answer to better explain what is happening...

Comment: Thank you for this wonderfully informative answer. For some reason that I do not fully understand, it appears that the transition from visible to hidden occurs at the end of the duration, whereas the transition from hidden to visible occurs at the beginning of the transition--I guess that dense verbiage from the spec is saying that's how it is supposed to work, which in any case is exactly how I want it to.

Comment: Not sure how the switch between visible,hidden happens. I have the following code:`.anim1 { 
  animation-name:blink;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes blink{ 
from {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
   
     to {
            visibility:visible;
      }
 }` I expected hidden at start point, then become visible at end point. However what it happens is my dom element keeps visible ALL time, no blink occurs

Answer (score 1):

As a good alternative to display/visibility toggle, `opacity:0` with `pointer-events:none` could be used.