# Transition on visibility property

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a menu that has a submenu and this is what I have for the moment (it's more complex than this), I want to use the **transition property:**

```
.product:hover #button-option {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
#button-option {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility .2s;
    transition: visibility .2s;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bsmq2kg/

I want my submenu to appear a little later, or like take some time to appear like in here: http://www.vmware.com

How could I make this work? I tried several things but none has been working. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm actually stupid and didn't realize a mistake there was in the code, but I still cannot find what I really wanted to find.

Comment: Post your html code also or make a fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating non-animatable properties with CSS3 transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605637/animating-non-animatable-properties-with-css3-transitions)

Comment: What does this have to do with sibling combinators?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I had a sibling combinator but then removed it, sorry

Comment: this is not working because your code is wrong. It should be something like `.product:hover > #button-option` . This being said, I'd avoid using visibility and try using a better option, like opacity or position

Answer (score 2):

Visibility will transition, but only in binary (on/off) fashion. Perhaps you want to transition on `opacity` in addition (since `visibility` needs to be off to prevent mouse detection on the element). You probably also don't need/want the `!important`. Also, unless you are targeting old browser versions, you don't need the `webkit-transition` prefixed property (if you're going to specify it, should be `-webkit-transition`).

Comment: If I put opacity, the submenu will "always" be there but just invisible, so the content under it wouldn't be accessible. I want something like this submenu: http://vmware.com

Comment: You need to combine `visiblility` and `opacity`; see the question this question is marked as a possible duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility will not animate well. For that you might better animate opacity:

```
#button-option {
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.product:hover #button-option {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If you want the menu to slide from left to right, then you can also animate position:

```
#button-option {
    left: -300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.product:hover #button-option {
    left: 0px;
}
```

You can check for more detail [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/).

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I mixed opacity with visibility, thank you all! going to try some of your suggestions too, Good Night!