# CSS Transition effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

Transition must happen when we move from one value to another upon a event.

Here the visibility setting on an element:

```
.two {
  background-color: #9fa8da;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 3ms ease-in;
}
```

Upon a button click, visibility is set to 'visible'

```
.two-show {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

However there is no animation effect.

Plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4Fhb1Uj744BRwCDhebOP?p=info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating non-animatable properties with CSS3 transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605637/animating-non-animatable-properties-with-css3-transitions)

Comment: A helpful guide: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the very same effect you want using the `opacity` property. [Updated your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DqeT673VyiNR0WCAtxIr?p=preview) using this new approach. I also increased the transition time for the effect to be noticeable.

```
.two {
  background-color: #9fa8da;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
}

.two-show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Nice job

Comment: Beat you by 9 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to .two{}:

```
-webkit-transition: visibility 30ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 3s;
-moz-transition: visibility 30ms ease-in;
-o-transition: visibility 30ms ease-in;
```

I wonder if 3ms is to fast?